# How to get slice of 3D data with affine transform in MayaVI

Tags: python, mayavi

I am visualizing scalar field which is defined on a regular but non-orthogonal and not aligned with 'x' 'y' 'z' coordinates grid. Volume visualization works perfectly by putting data to regular grid and applying affine transform like this

```
self.volume_data_plot =  self.scene.mlab.pipeline.volume(self.data_src3d)
aff_m = ...  # set affine matrix
m=tvtk.Matrix4x4()
m.from_array(aff_m)
# apply scaling matrix to volume data
self.volume_data_plot.actors[0].poke_matrix(m)
self.volume_data_plot.update_pipeline()
```

However, when I am trying to do 2D cut plane of the same data, I am lost. I've tried `image_plane_widget` and `scalar_cut_plane` with no success: they have no actor to apply affine transform to. Or, at least, I can not find how to get them. Mayavi help system is not helpful too: only trivial stuff is documented. Could anyone help?